# QGIS parameter for opening

Tags: qgis

I use two screens and the QGIS version 3.4.8 LTR. Is there any parameter, for example in the QGIS3.ini or the qgis_global_settings.ini, in which is stored on which screen qgis is always started?

Comment: Which OS is it? What have you tried?

Comment: The OS is Win10

Comment: did you read here ??
https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html?highlight=noplugins#running-qgis-with-advanced-settings